# js crossing two function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm beginer in js, please help me.

I have two functions. First function sum all checked input ticket and view sum price, secondary function check discount code and takes into account the new price.

The problem is when I add a discount code and then will choose a ticket. Then it does not calculate the value.

https://jsfiddle.net/wznvfkm3/

```js
$('.participantEventTicket').on('change', function() {

  var totalPrice = 0.00;
  $('.participantEventTicket:checked').each(function() {
    totalPrice += parseFloat($(this).data('price'), 10);
  });
  $('.participantEventTicketSum').html(totalPrice.toFixed(2));
  $('.participantEventTicketDiscountValueTotal').html(totalPrice);
});

$('.participantEventTicketDiscount').on('change', function() {

  var code = ($(this).val());
  var valueTotal = document.getElementById('participantEventTicketSum').innerHTML;
  var value = 0;
  var liste = [];
  liste[0] = ['ABB'], -5]; liste[1] = ['BBC'], -10];
for (var i = 0, len = liste.length; i < len; i++) {
  if (liste[i][0] === code) {
    var value = liste[i][1];
  }
}
var valueTotalS = parseInt(valueTotal) + parseFloat(value);

$('#participantEventTicketDiscountValue').html(value.toFixed(2));
$('#participantEventTicketDiscountValueTotal').html(valueTotalS);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  ticket 1
  <input type="checkbox" name="participantEventTicket[]" value="5" class="participantEventTicket" />
  <br/>ticket 2
  <input type="checkbox" name="participantEventTicket[]" value="10" class="participantEventTicket" />
  <br/>Sume tickets: <span class="participantEventTicketSum" id="participantEventTicketSum">0.00</span>
  <br/>Discount coupon
  <input type="text" id="participantEventTicketDiscount" class="participantEventTicketDiscount">
  <br/>Discount value <span id="participantEventTicketDiscountValue" class="participantEventTicketDiscountValue">0.00</span>
  <br/>Discount value sum <span id="participantEventTicketDiscountValueTotal" class="participantEventTicketDiscountValueTotal">0.00</span>
</form>
```

Comment: I created a snippet for you - and you need to add jQuery to your JSFiddle too. The snippet already shows error you need to fix. `['ABB'], -5]; liste[1] = ['BBC'], -10];` is invalid JS. Also this `document.getElementById('participantEventTicketSum').innerHTML;` is the same as `$('#participantEventTicketSum').html();`

Answer (score 0):

Slawotu,

Please check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wznvfkm3/2/)
You had couple errors:

```
$('.participantEventTicket:checked').each(function () { totalPrice += parseFloat($(this).val(), 10);}); 
// you supposed to take $(this).val()
```

You didn't put calculation of total Price when you entered discount and changed you ticket:

```
$('.participantEventTicketDiscountValueTotal').html(totalPrice + value);
```

Forgot but brackets:

```
liste[0] = [['ABB'], -5];
liste[1] = [['BBC'], -10];
```

You compared 2 different objects using === instead use ==

```
if (liste[i][0] == code)
```

Declare val on top of the file, don't declare inside if statement.

```
var value = 0;
```

Comment: Two days working on a solution to this problem, feel bad asking for help.

Comment: I have last question. How to delete promo code? When entering the code, I want to go back to the entry point. Removing the code, it remains a promotional value

Comment: I updated fiddle above. Edit your original question.